# AJAX pass 2 variables into the php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = 1;
    var name = "Abu";

    $.post("update.php", {id: id, name: name}, function(data)
    {

    });
});
</script>
```

update.php

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    echo $id.'<br />';
    echo $name.'<br />';
?>
```

From the above code, I want to use jquery pass the id and name from js to the update.php to update the record. However, I get the following error: **Undefined index ...**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the complete error?

Comment: Undefined index: id in update.php on line X, Undefined index: name in update.php on line X

Comment: Which line is "Line X"? Is it `$id = $_POST['id'];`?

Comment: @WesFoster Yes, it is.

Comment: inspect the post request to see if the variables are being posted at all.

Comment: Inspect the network request of the Ajax call. Do you see the post values? Are you sure your JS code is not cache with an old version? Is that the exact code?

Comment: Why would adding json datatype make a difference with the sending the values to the server? @Vishnu Issue has nothing to do with the response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hii michael you can set the ajax post request like this

```
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'abc.php',
            data: {box:id,keys:name},
            success: function(msg) {
             alert(msg);
             }
           });
```

then in php file you can check with isset if value is set or not

Comment: `$.post` is just  a shorthand wrapper for `$.ajax`, normally both should work or both souldn't work because they behave the same internally. minus one because this answer is not resolving the issue (The use of one of them depend on the project, ajax settings)

Answer (score 0):

You can also test other approaches (since you still don't show more details from your element inspector)with following things:

1.Name attributes in POST data with serialized string:

```
    var data = "name=nameString";
    $.post("file", data, function(data) {

    }, "json");
```

2.Or use map:

```
var data = {
            name : "name"
            };
    $.post("file", data, function(data) {
        }, "json");
```

To handle this variable in PHP , keep the same use:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```